# MemoryUsage init size in grater than max size

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, javabeans

I config my own heap size using vm argument:

```
-Xmx5g
-Xms5g
-XX:NewSize=1g
```

I try to monitor my application's heap usages using java mxbeans:

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage()
```

The strange thing is that I am getting results that does not make sense
The heap init size is grater than the max heap size

```
init = 5368709120(5242880K)
used = 209032600(204133K)
committed = 5145034752(5024448K)
max = 5145034752(5024448K)
```

any idea how is it possible?

BTW, if i am running jvisualvm i can see the max value right:
[image]

Comment: Max is the memory the Jvm can address for your programm. Some memory is always reserved for management.

Comment: the heap init size is right: `-Xms5g` = 1024^3 * 5 = 5368709120 but Java cannot use all the memory because it's not available

Comment: Please see the image I added, it seems like jvisualvm knows how to read the right numbers.
anyway, i would expect the max heap size to be grater than or equals init size and not the other way around